# I am trying to use keys to preserve the state of the widgets and remove the blinking effect when setState is called

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, setstate

I am trying to remove the blinking/flashing effect after the widgets are rebuild. I read about keys, but it's not working, I added a unique key to every GridView builder element as you see in the code below.
Now when I resize, the widgets are rebuilt because the *setState* function is called but I can not preserve their state.

```
  void addOutfitPlannerDialog(BuildContext context) async{
    await showGeneralDialog(
        barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Transform.scale(
          scale: a1.value,
          child: Opacity(
          opacity: a1.value,
            child: AlertDialog(
            actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
            titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
            buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            title: _getBackAndSaveButtons(context),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            content:  StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: 100.w,
              height: 100.h,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    child:
                    Container(
                      width: 100.w,
                      height: 82.h,
                      color: const Color(0xff393432),
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100.w,
                          height: 100.h,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 10, 45, 15.h),
                          child: Screenshot(
                            controller: screenshotController,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: stackChildren,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: heightBottomOutfitPlanner,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide( //                    <--- top side
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      width: 100.w,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 100.w,
                            height: 8.h,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 7,
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      itemCount: outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList
                                          .length,
                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                          int index) {
                                        return InkWell(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            getOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages(
                                                outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index],
                                                setState);
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                30, 0, 30, 0),
                                            decoration: (outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index] ==
                                                myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages[0]
                                                    .closetOrganizer) ||
                                                (outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index] ==
                                                    "To Buy" &&
                                                    myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages[0]
                                                        .closetOrganizer ==
                                                        null)
                                                ? const BoxDecoration(
                                              border: Border(
                                                bottom: BorderSide( //                    <--- top side
                                                  color: Color(0xffE4BCB4),
                                                  width: 3.0,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            )
                                                : null,
                                            child: Center(child: Text(
                                                outfitPlanerOrganizerEntriesList[index],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: SizerUtil
                                                      .deviceType ==
                                                      DeviceType.mobile
                                                      ? 16
                                                      : 25,
                                                ))),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(width: 30),
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 1,
                                  child: Container(
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border(
                                          left: BorderSide( //                    <--- top side
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            width: 1.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onPanStart: (details) =>
                                            _handleDrag(details, setState),
                                        onPanUpdate: (details) =>
                                            _handleUpdate(details, setState),
                                        child: Icon(Icons.drag_indicator,
                                          size: SizerUtil.deviceType ==
                                              DeviceType.mobile ? 35 : 45,
                                        ),
                                      )

                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5),
                          !isLoadingOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages ? Container(
                            width: 100.w,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                            height: heightBottomOutfitPlanner - 10.h,
                            child: GridView.builder(
                                physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                                  maxCrossAxisExtent: SizeConfig.screenWidth! /
                                      4,),
                                itemCount: myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages
                                    .length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                                  return InkWell(
                                    key: Key(index.toString()),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      try {
                                        removeBackground(ctx, setState, CleverCloset.dataFromBase64String(myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages[index].getImage!));
                                      }
                                      catch (e) {
                                        stackChildren.add(MoveableStackItem(CleverCloset.imageFromBase64String(myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages[index].getImage!).image));
                                      }
                                      },
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(20))
                                      ),
                                      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth! / 4,
                                      height: SizeConfig.screenWidth! / 4,
                                      child: FittedBox(
                                        child:
                                        FadeInImage(
                                          placeholder: const AssetImage(
                                              'assets/placeholder.gif'),
                                          image: CleverCloset
                                              .imageFromBase64String(
                                              myOutfitPlannerTabTappedImages[index]
                                                  .getImage!)
                                              .image,
                                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        ),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                            ),
                          ) : Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
            )
          ),
            ),
          ),
        );
    },
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    barrierDismissible: false,
    barrierLabel: '',
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {return Container();}
    );
  }
```

[image: output gif]

Comment: Did you find out?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below logic to your code. It basically gets executed when the widget has build.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => function(context));
}
```

And now you can implement the `function(context)` to do what you need to do after the build.

Comment: I don't think I understand the relevance of this answer with my questions...